# Excel: Reduce task list to the next three items in line based on task status

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to summary area for a task list. I have list of about 20 tasks that I need to complete for jobs. As the task are completed I change the status from "blank" to "Complete". When that occurs, I want the summary area to repopulate with the next three upcoming tasks. The areas highlighted in yellow are the cells I am trying to have autopopulate. Column C is where I change the status from "Blank" to "Complete". In this example image, because the first 3 tasks are completed, the next three that would populate are "Rebar Inspection", "Gunite", and "Trench". What formula can I use to accomplish this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can use the `INDEX`, `FILTER` and `SEQUENCE` functions to the desired output. Assuming your data ranges from A8 to C16 (see image below), enter the formula in B2:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B8:B16,C8:C16=""),SEQUENCE(3,1))
```

Change the ranges to conform to yours.

[image: Result]

Comment: This worked out perfectly. I appreciate the quick help!

Comment: @Nick In this community, if this answer was helpful, you're invited to upvote it. Moreover, if it is the correct answer, you are invited to mark it as such. This will help others with similar problems to find the correct solution. Thank you.